# Is there a name for smaller parts of a glyph in typography?

Tags: typography, terminology, glyphs

My understanding is that a symbol in typography is often called a glyph. There are cases when one glyph is composed of multiple "components" with space in between them, e.g. `:`, `;`, etc.

Is there any name for these "components" (e.g. one dot in a colon)?

Comment: Isn't *"one dot in a colon"* called a period? `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Most parts of letters are named, and there are some terms which only apply to a single letter. For example the spine of the S.

Here is a good article to read.

https://visme.co/blog/type-anatomy/

Comment: more glyph component names here https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/lF5ZdcjV-UCtGgpE66bzRP-Fq0j6En1n4SydXZpLzgInRuozY2-q6dJTB5y7kmfcUBKgZfp0U1jAY7G9i0clMR97wLVdLa_69i9SQQVp4f-hIo1B-q7NFjejWquYs6tR=w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a name for these "components", just like there's no name for the dot in the letter i, for example. They're just part of the glyph.

Comment: [No name for the dot of an *i*, you say?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle)